# why does it print log twice while my code only allow one

Tags: javascript

I was doing this codewar kata: http://www.codewars.com/kata/52a89c2ea8ddc5547a000863/train/javascript

**please check this pic:** [kata instructions and my test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSRaR.jpg)

my code:

```
function loop_size(node){
    var n = 0;
    while (!node.sign) {
        node["sign"] = n;
        n++;
        node = node.next;
    }
    console.log('n: ' + n);
    console.log('node.sign: '+ node.sign);
    return n - node.sign;
}
```

but my code fails because of: **Value is not what was expected**

I found it print log twice, and the value of both n and node.sign modified to 1, I can't figure out what happened, someone good at javascript please help, thank you.

Comment: Should show the test, too.

Comment: there is a pic attached at the end.

Comment: The picture only shows the output, it doesn't show what the input data is. How is the function called? Probably the test is calling your function multiple times with different values.

Comment: I did't know the what the argument exactly is. I begin to suspect there is a bug in this kata....btw, I have edit the pic.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution passed the first test, but not the rest. Because the rest tests was designed to prevent the solutions like yours to pass. Try not to modify the node itself.
Your log appeared twice because the test was mean to run twice with the same nodes, and because you try to mark the node with .sign property, so it will alway fail on the second assertion.

Comment: appreciate your answer very much, I try to resolve in a new way. Thank you